# How can I send multiple parameters from Angular HTTP Post to Nodejs backend to use in OracleDB query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, post

My post is successful and I am getting data returned to me in Angular but for some reason I cannot pass the variable of "id" with a value of "11". I have search various tutorials and to me it looks like I have it setup correctly.

Am I missing something easy here? I am a newbie so apologize in advance if this is easy.

Angular Page Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DBService, Group} from '../db.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common/src/directives/ng_if';
import { element } from 'protractor';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-flow',
  templateUrl: './flow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../css.css']
})
export class FlowComponent implements OnInit {

  groups: Group[];

  constructor(
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
    private dbService: DBService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}



  ngOnInit() {
   const id = 11;
    this.dbService.getGroup2(id).subscribe(groups => this.groups = groups);
  }

}
```

DB Service Code

```js
getGroup2(id): Observable<Group[]> {
 const url = 'http://localhost:4200/api/' + 'employees';
 const params = ({
id: id
 });
 return this._http.post(url, params)
 .pipe(
  map((res) => {
     console.log(res);
    return <Group[]> res;
  })
 );
 }
```

**Backend**

services/router.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const employees = require('../controllers/employees.js');

router.route('/employees/:id?')
  .post(employees.post);

module.exports = router;
```

services/database.js

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('../config/database.js');

async function initialize() {
  const pool = await oracledb.createPool(dbConfig.hrPool);
}

module.exports.initialize = initialize;

// close the function

async function close() {
    await oracledb.getPool().close();
  }
  
  module.exports.close = close;

// simple executre function

function simpleExecute(statement, binds = [], opts = {}) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let conn;
  
      opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
      opts.autoCommit = true;
  
      try {
        conn = await oracledb.getConnection();
  
        const result = await conn.execute(statement, binds, opts);
  
        resolve(result);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      } finally {
        if (conn) { // conn assignment worked, need to close
          try {
            await conn.close();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
  module.exports.simpleExecute = simpleExecute;
```

controllers/employees.js

```js
const employees = require('../db_apis/employees.js');

async function get(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const context = {};

  context.id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

    const rows = await employees.find(context);

    if (req.params.id) {
      if (rows.length === 1) {
        res.status(200).json(rows[0]);
      } else {
        res.status(404).end();
      }
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}

module.exports.get = get;
```

db_apis/employees.js

```js
const database = require('../services/database.js');

const baseQuery = 
 `SELECT * FROM DB.EMPLOYEES`;

async function find(context) {
  let query = baseQuery;
  const binds = {};

   if (context.id) {
   binds.employee_id = context.id;

    query += `\nwhere employee_id = :employee_id`;
  }

  const result = await database.simpleExecute(baseQuery);
  
  console.log(result.rows);
  return result.rows;

}

module.exports.find = find;
```

Note I am just trying to get this to work for 1 variable in my code above for ID. In the future I am going to need to pass **multiple** variables like dates, numbers, and varchar strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
req.params.id
```

Try to use:

```
req.body['id']
```

[`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) is used to get parameters from route

Comment: I made the change and received the following error:

    express_1  | TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    express_1  |     at post (/app/controllers/employees.js:7:36)

Comment: I've updated the code, try that please. If it didn't work, try to open the browser inspect element, go to **Network** tab and see if the post request is sending the body correctly. Then, try to console.log(req.body)

Comment: When I do a console log of the entire req I do not see if my variable anywhere.

However in the Network tab if I looks at the employees call I do see a section called Request Payload that has {id: 2}. Which is what I need.